# Generate polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Given solutions of a n degree polynomial , how can we find the polynomial.
Eg. : I have solutions like :

For x = 3, answer = 2

```
x = 4, answer = 1.77778

x = 5, answer =  1.660800
```

Comment: do you mean f(x) such that ? ,$$f(3)=2\\f(4)=1.77778\\f(5)=1.660800$$

Comment: did you mean solutions or values at x=**? Why not try interpolation to generate a polynomial?

Comment: you can use interpolation , or  suppose f(x) is a polynomial in 2 dgree 
$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$ apply points in it , and find a,b,c

Comment: Yes @ darya khosrotash

Answer (score 0):

Use the Lagrange interpolation formula. If you are given that $P(x_i) = y_i$ for $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, then one solution is
$$
P(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \prod_{j \neq i} \frac{x - x_j}{x_i - x_j}.
$$
Compute $P(x_i)$ yourself to see why you get $y_i$.